# Replace first few characters of field in an update statement

Tags: sql

Trying to solve this one out on update statement. Each field has same number of characters and format like 'abc-def-ghi'

How do I replace the 'abc-def' part with 'xxx-xxx' if the field contains 'abc'?

Comment: Take a look at [substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of [`substr`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr)s and string concatenations should do the trick:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET    col1 = CONCAT('xxx-xxx-' , SUBSTR(col1, 9))
WHERE  col1 LIKE '%abc%'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
IF(col LIKE '%abc%', REPLACE(col, 'abc-def', 'xxx-xxx'), col)
```

Comment: @user406151:  But you have access to it in a variable, right?  So just plug it in.